# Upgrading to Tomcat 8, JSPs not working

Tags: jsp, web.xml, tomcat8

I have a web app running in Tomcat 6. I try to run it in Tomcat 8 and if I hit a JSP URL, it just serves it as a plain file (ie, I see the JSP code). I see Tomcat defines the `jsp` servlet in a default `web.xml` file. Any idea why it wouldn't be used?

**Update**

There was a mapping for the `jsp` servlet in the app's web.xml. Apparently old Tomcat allowed you to *add* to the default mapping like this. While Tomcat 8 replaced the default mapping.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/more-jsps/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: any arrors or warning in startup log?

Comment: Do you using some proxy server like Apache or nginx?

Comment: Have you tried to change <web-app> tag schema-location,version etc configuration? Have you tried to making new project with single jsp and deploy project on the same server then see what happens...

Comment: I added "Update" to question. I guess mappings use to accumulate, and now they replace.